# List append VS. += getting UnboundLocalError in inner function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've following code which raise Exception:

```
def a():
     b = []
     def inner():
         b += 3
     inner()
     print (b)

>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 6, in a
  File "<console>", line 5, in inner
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
```

But, If I rewrite the code like this, it runs as expected:

```
def a():
     b = []
     def inner():
         b.append(5)
     inner()
     print(b)

>>> a()
[5]
```

I'd like to know why this is happening, thanks.

Comment: Note that `+=` on a list is equivalent to `extend`, rather than `append`. Even if you used the `nonlocal` keyword to fix the scoping issue, you'd need to change your first version to `b += [3]` for it to work.

Comment: Yes, I knew it as @Andrew mentioned this in his answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find an exact explanation. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/

> If you’re closely following the Python tag on StackOverflow, you’ll
>   notice that the same question comes up at least once a week.
>
> <..>
>
> Although this exact question is answered in Python’s official FAQ ([right here](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)), I
>   decided to write this article with the intent of giving a deeper explanation.
>
> <..>
>
> So where does the exception come from? Quoting the FAQ:
>
> > This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope,
> >     that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any
> >     similarly named variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the two is that `b += 3` is an assignment -- it is assigning a totally new value (the result of addition of your empty list and 3) to `b`.  `b.append()`, in contrast, mutates the list referenced by `b` without reassigning it.

`inner()` is accessing a variable in its parent's scope (I think this is not technically a closure since the execution of the parent has not completed).  But `inner()` can only dereference that name, not assign to it, because `b` is not local to `inner()` and is not declared as `global` or `nonlocal`.

So you can dereference `b` and mutate the list it refers to, but you cannot assign to it.  When you try to assign to it by starting the line with `b +=` you are saying "treat `b` like a local".  On a normal `b = 3` assignment this would actually complete successfully, creating a local variable like any other.  But in this case, since `b` has no already assigned value in the local context, *dereferencing `b` in order to perform the addition procedure* fails.

As it happens, you can't simply add an integer to a list in the first place. `+=` is not the same thing as `append` even setting aside assignment vs. mutation, so even if you weren't reaching out of scope it would fail with a `TypeError`.  `b += [3]` is closer to what you mean, although it will still fail due to the variable's scope.

Comment: @eryksun What is a free variable?